# DBLink From AIX Oracle To Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle, odbc, aix, psqlodbc

Is it possible to create a DBLink from Oracle 11G which is running on AIX 7.1 to PostgreSQL? I couldn't find postgresql-odbc for AIX.

Oracle 11G - AIX 7.1
PostgreSQL 9.3.5 - Linux

Thanks for advance.

Comment: It should work (I think you'd need Oracle Golden Gate), but on AIX you have to build the ODBC driver from source.

Comment: Hi Laurenz. Thanks for your reply. unixODBC has been installed on AIX. But also postgresql-odbc needs to be installed as well since I need to use "psqlodbcw.so" and "libodbcpsqlS.so" files which come with postgresql-odbc. The problem is I am not sure if postgresql-odbc is available for AIX 7.1. I tried to copy those files from a Linux. Then I get following error (/usr/lib64 has psqlodbcw.so file);

[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

Comment: You cannot use Linux binaries on AIX. You will have to compile and link the source code. If you ask that question, I suspect that you are not familiar with that process, so that may be more than you can handle. You need a C compiler, `make`, etc. That exceeds the scope of a Stackoverflow answer.